# How do I custom build a homebrew package?

Tags: phantomjs, homebrew

This [Homebrew Cookbook manual](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Homebrew/homebrew/file/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md) is helpful in giving some clues on how the `homebrew`system works. I have installed PhantomJS using `brew install phantomjs`, but I need to apply some patches. I can see that the formula already has a patch applied:

```
# Qt Yosemite build fix. Upstream commit/PR:                                                                                     
# https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/commit/70e442                                                                               
# https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/12934                                                                                  
patch do                                                                                                                         
  url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/patches/480b7142c4e2ae07de6028f672695eb927a34875/phantomjs/yosemite.patch"     
  sha256 "f54bd1592185f031552d3ad5c8809ff27e8f3be4f1c05c81b59bf7dbc4a59de1"                                                      
end
```

**What is the 'correct' way to modify the source and rebuild?** I suppose I could modify the source, repackage it using `tar/gz`, place it in the cache folder, and then change the checksum in the formula, but is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your patches like the one that’s already there:

```
patch do
    url "https://where.your.patch/is"
    sha256 "... its checksum ..."
end

patch do
    url "https://another.patch.url"
    sha256 "... its checksum ..."
end
```

Make sure it’s in the `stable do` block like the existing patch.

Then run `brew install --build-from-source phantomjs`. Once it’s installed, edit the formula to its original state or your next `brew update` will fail.

If you know what you’re doing you can avoid adding `sha256`s to each patch; Homebrew will warn you it can’t verify them but won’t abort the install.

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for this? Can I assume that `url` accepts all well-formed urls? (i.e. `file://tomyownlocal.patch`)

Comment: You can also embed patches directly into the formula; the documentation is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#patches